# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^c} \ll \frac{1}{(c-1)^2}$ for $c>1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{n^c} \ll \frac{1}{(c-1)^2}$ for $c>1$.

It seems like I need to use some sort of integral comparison, since $\int_1^\infty dt/t^c=1/(c-1)$.

So using integration by parts, we have $\int_1^\infty \frac{\log t}{t^c}dt = \frac{t^{-c+1}}{-c+1} \log t |_1^\infty + \int_1^\infty \frac{t^{-c}}{c-1}dt = \frac{1}{(c-1)^2},$ using the fact that for $1-c>0$, $\log t/ t^{1-c} \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

However, I am not sure why the integral bounds the sum i.e. we have $|\sum_n \frac{\log n}{n^c}| \le 1/(c-1)^2=\int_1^\infty \log t/ t^c dt$. Why is the integral the big Oh of the sum over natural numbers?

Comment: Draw the function curve and draw the rectangles for left Riemann sum and right Riemann sum, compare the area and you will see.

Comment: @MathFail Does the fact that $\log$ is less than $0$ for $x<e$ not matter in the comparison?

Comment: $n$ start from $1$.

Comment: @MathFail Yes but the first two terms are negative and looking at the graph https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Calculus/550386 for $c=2$ for example, I cannot really see how to compare the sum and the integral areas. Could you perhaps provide a more mathematical explanation?

Comment: $\ln x\ge0$ for $x\ge1$, how can it be negative?

Comment: @MathFail Right that was a dumb mistake by me. But looking at the graph the function seems to initially increase from $1$ to $2$ then decrease from $2$ onwards so how can we be sure that the areas of the integral will be bigger than the areas of the sum(which is the Left Riemann sum)?

Comment: *Hint.* For $c > 0$, $n \geq 2$, and $x \in (n-1, n]$, we have $$\frac{\log n}{n^c} = \frac{\log\lceil x\rceil}{\lceil x\rceil^c} \leq \frac{\log(2x)}{x^c}.$$ Then using this, obtain the bound $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^c} \leq \frac{1}{(c-1)^2} + \frac{\log 2}{c-1} $$ and conclude. (Numerical experiments suggest that the term $\frac{\log 2}{c-1}$ is redundant, but establishing this seems fairly non-trivial.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Why is the sum of the RHS bounded by the integral of the RHS?

Comment: Using the inequality, you get $$ \frac{\log n}{n^c} = \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{\log n}{n^c} \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{\log(2x)}{x^c} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$ Now sum this for $n=2,3,4,\ldots$

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks for the comment but I have no clue as to why $1/(c-1) = O(1/(c-1)^2)$ because we actually have $1/(c-1)^2 = O(1/(c-1))$ if $c>2$. Are you positive that $\log 2/ (c-1)$ is redundant? I think this only holds for $1<c\le 2$.

Comment: I assumed that you are concerned with the regime $c \to 1^+$. Of course my bound does not work literally when $c\to\infty$, but this is easily and independently resolved by noting that the sum decays exponentially fast as $c\to\infty$: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^c}\leq\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^c}\leq \frac{1}{2^{c-1}}+\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{c-1}}\ll 2^{-c}\ll\frac{1}{(c-1)^2}\quad\text{as $c\to\infty$}$$